# Probability of creating a triangular frame from a straight stick

Tags: probability

If you have a straight stick and you break it in exactly two places what is the probability that the three pieces if put together can create a triangular frame?

This is exactly the question my professor gave on our statistics and probability final.
I analyzed it as best as I could (I wrote a whole page filled with assumptions and limitations) but I would like to know if anyone can come up with a scientific valid answer.

Comment: You need an assumption on the probability distribution used to select the two places where you break the stick.

Comment: In the case that they're uniformly distributed, see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-re

Comment: Bring in the *whole page*.

Comment: @did i don't have it, it was an exam.. :)

Comment: Can you reconstruct it?

Comment: I assumed the stick was one meter long and said that x1<x2+x3 & x2<x1+x3 & x3<x1+x2 . I also said that assuming we can't make a cut smaller than one mm we can make 1000 different cuts for the first one and 999 cuts for the second. And all that would result in 1e+6 ways we can cut the stick. At that point I starting running out of logical arguments and assumed the first cut had to be in the [0.2-0.4] of either end so 2*0.2=0.4 and the second cut [0.2-0.4]  of the end of the bigger of the two sticks meaning 0.2 and multiplied them.. which I realised even as I wrote it that it was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Without loss of generality we may assume the stick to be of unit length. Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two random positions where the stick was broken. Then length of three sticks obtained are $$
 \ell_1 = \min(X_1,X_2), \quad \ell_2 = \max(X_1,X_2) - \min(X_1,X_2), \quad \ell_3 = 1-\max(X_1,X_2)
$$ 
It is possible to form a triangle out of these sticks, provided triangle inequalities hold true:
$$
    \ell_3 < \ell_1+\ell_2 \quad  \ell_1 < \ell_2+\ell_3 \quad \ell_2 < \ell_1+\ell_3
$$
which are satisfied provided
$$
 \Omega =  \left(   0 < X_2 < \frac{1}{2} < X_1 < \frac{1}{2} + X_2 \right)    \lor 
  \left( X_2 - \frac{1}{2} < X_1 < \frac{1}{2} < X_2 < 1 \right)
$$

[image]

The probability of this event, given the joint pdf of $(X_1,X_2)$, $f(x_1,x_2)$ equals:
$$
   \mathbb{P}(\Omega) =  \int f(x_1,x_2) \mathbf{1}_\Omega\left(x_1,x_2\right) \mathrm{d} x_1 \mathrm{d} x_2
$$
In the case of uniform distribution, $f(x_1, x_2) = 1$, and the probability is easily seen to equal $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: I understood the first part until the plot and the integration. Could you please elaborate your answer further or share a link of some resources which can lead a novice to understand such topics fully? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not any good at math, nor do I understand much about probability, but I've always approached this problem from graphically.

Lets say the length of the stick is 1 and assume that the cuts on the sticks are distributed uniformly. Lets call the distance from the left end of the stick to the first cut $x$, and the distance from the stick to the second cut $y$, and lets assume that the stick is of length 1:

[image]

We know that the sum of any two sides of a triangle must be greater than the third side. Thus we have:

$$x + (y-x) > 1-y$$
$$(y-x)+(1-y)>x$$
$$x+(1-y)>y-x$$

And simplifying:

$$y>.5$$
$$.5>x$$
$$x+.5>y$$

Let us also add the condition that the $y$ is the first plus second piece starting from the left, and x is always the first piece, so:
$$y>x$$

We also know that the most the $x$ piece can be in length is 1, and the least is 0, same with y, so we add conditions:

$$1>x>0$$
$$1>y>0$$

If you graph out the last 3 conditions I gave then that graphically will give you the whole area where it is possible for you to get when you do the two cuts, and then the first 3 conditions I gave will give you the piece of that area that allows you to make a triangle. I don't know how to draw a graph, but you should get a smaller triangle that is 1/4 the bigger triangle, meaning .25 chance of getting a triangle with 2 uniformly distributed cuts.